# Prove that $P = \frac{1}{2}(I - \operatorname{sign}(A))$ is a projection onto $\mathcal{V}$.

Tags: control-theory

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the invariant subspace of a matrix $A$ corresponding to eigenvalues with negative real parts. How do I show that $P = \frac{1}{2}(I - \operatorname{sign}(A))$ is a projection onto $\mathcal{V}$? Any hint would be appreciated.

**Definition**: Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\Re(\lambda)\neq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \Lambda(A)$. Let

\begin{equation}
A = S 
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&J_+
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}
\end{equation}

be the Jordan normal form of $A$ where $J_- \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times k}$ and $J_+ \in \mathbb{C}^{n-k \times n-k}$ are such that $\Lambda(J_-) \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)<0\}$ and $\Lambda(J_+) \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)>0\}$. Then the *sign* of $A$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{sign}(A) := S 
\begin{bmatrix}
-I&0\\
0&I
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: Are you sure that this really is a projection? I got $$ P^2 = \frac{1}{4}(2I - 2sign(A)) $$ if this really is a projection, then this would imply $sign(A)=-I$. I don't think, that this is always true. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What is your difficulty?  If you write $P=S\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}S^{-1}$, doesn't it follow immediately that $P$ is a projection onto $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven From what you've written, clearly $P^{2}=P,$ as required of a projection. This does not imply $\mathrm{sign}(A)=-I,$ however.

Comment: @Batominovski I see that $P = \frac{1}{2}(I^{n \times n} - \operatorname{sign}(A)) = \frac{1}{2} (I^{n \times n} - S \begin{bmatrix}
-I^{k \times k}&0\\
0&I^{n-k \times n-k}
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}) = \ldots = S \begin{bmatrix}
I^{k \times k}&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}$ and that $P^2=P$. However I'm not yet convinced that $P$ is indeed a projection onto $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Thanks for your remark. It was already late and I somehow made the stupid mistake that I should get $P^2=I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be matrices.
Starting with $P = \frac{1}{2}(I-\operatorname{sign}(A))$ we use the definition of $\operatorname{sign}(A)$ to obtain 
$P = S
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}$.
We use this result to show that there exists a matrix $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $AP = PB$: 
$\begin{align*}
AP &= S 
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&J_+
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} S 
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} = 
S
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&J_+
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} =
S
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} \\ &= 
S
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} =
S
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1} \underbrace{S
\begin{bmatrix}
J_-&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
S^{-1}}_{=:B} = PB.
\end{align*}
$
Let $\mathcal{V} := \operatorname{im}(P)$. Then it follows that $\mathcal{V}$ is $A$-invariant.